# Update LiveCharts from datatable dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I have been reading documentation for several days now but I can't get it working, no matter what I try. I have Basic Row chart and want to display as a graph time spent. My bar title and value are changing constantly (more items getting added). I am able to add bars with my current code, but I am not able to add title for each added bar. Only first title / first bar title is visible, all the others / coming are not visible.

How to add title and value in a proper way? (I am already familiar with documentation https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wf/Basic%20Row)

Here is my code (you can see from commented out sections what has been tried yet):

```
    public static SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
    public static string[] Labels { get; set; }
    public static List<string> LabelsList { get; set; }
    public static Func<double, string> Formatter { get; set; }

    public AppUsageBarGraph()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LabelsList = new List<string>();

        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new RowSeries
            {
                Values = new ChartValues<double> { },
                DataLabels = true
            }
        };

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public static void UpdateChart()
    {
        SeriesCollection[0].Values.Clear();
        LabelsList.Clear();

        //Labels = MainProcess.ActivityLogGrouped.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["Window Title"].ToString()).ToArray();

        foreach (DataRow row in MainProcess.ActivityLogGrouped.Rows)
        {
            SeriesCollection[0].Values.Add(Convert.ToDouble(row["Time Spent"]));
            //SeriesCollection[0]. = row["Time Spent"].ToString());
            LabelsList.Add(row["Window Title"].ToString());
        }

        //MessageBox.Show(Labels[0].ToString());

        Labels = LabelsList.ToArray(); 


        //foreach (var item in Labels)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(item);
        //}

        //Labels = new[]
        //        {
        //              "Shea Ferriera",
        //              "Maurita Powel",
        //              "Scottie Brogdon",
        //              "Teresa Kerman",
        //              "Nell Venuti",
        //              "Anibal Brothers",
        //              "Anderson Dillman"
        //           };

        //Formatter = value => value.ToString("N");
    }
```

Comment: Hi! The collection that is the binding source of the axis labels has to be of type `ObservableCollection` so that Clear/Move/Add/Remove will trigger the control (binding target) to update. Your properties should be public only and not public static and they should also be defined in a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` to avoid memory leaks (when used as data binding source).

Comment: @BionicCode hello! I understand that I should not use `LabelsList.Clear();` commands and use Binding instead, but `Labels` seems to be a string array `string[] Labels`? How I can add values to array so they would correspond Values? I am getting info of Active window and adding information to DataTable, I would like to show values from DataTable in my Chart in WPF window. Is there any example how to implement this kind of approach with getting DataTable to Chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use a `ObservableCollection<string>` instead of a `string[]`.

I also recommend to use a model to encapsulate the actual chart data points. I introduced the class `DataModel` for this reason.

The following example shows how to dynamically bind values and labels to the chart. I should say that making everything `public static` is a very bad smelling code design.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <wpf:CartesianChart Height="500">
    <CartesianChart.Series>
      <RowSeries Values="{Binding ChartModel.RowSeries}"
                 Configuration="{Binding ChartModel.RowSeriesConfiguration}"/>
    </CartesianChart.Series>
    <CartesianChart.AxisY>
      <Axis Labels="{Binding ChartModel.RowSeriesLabels}" />
    </CartesianChart.AxisY>
  </CartesianChart>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.ChartModel = new ChartModel();
  }

  public void UpdateChart()
  {
    foreach (DataRow row in MainProcess.ActivityLogGrouped.Rows)
    {
      if (double.TryParse(row["Time Spent"], out double value)
      {
        string label = row["Window Title"];
        var newDataModel = new DataModel(value, label);

        this.ChartModel.RowSeries.Add(newDataModel);            
        this.ChartModel.RowSeriesLabels.Add(newDataModel.Label);
      }
    }
  }

  public ChartModel ChartModel { get; set; }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**ChartModel.cs**

```
public class ChartModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ChartModel()
  {
    // Initialize chart
    this.RowSeries = new ChartValues<DataModel>()
    {
      new DataModel(20, "Shea Ferriera"),
      new DataModel(100, "Maurita Powel"),
      new DataModel(60, "Scottie Brogdon"),
    };

    // Create labels
    this.RowSeriesLabels = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    foreach (DataModel dataModel in this.RowSeries)
    {
      this.RowSeriesLabels.Add("dataModel.Label");
    }

    // DatModel to value mapping
    this.RowSeriesConfiguration = new CartesianMapper<DataModel>()
      .X(dataModel => dataModel.Value);
  }

  public CartesianMapper<DataModel> RowSeriesConfiguration { get; set; }
  public ChartValues<DataModel> RowSeries { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<string> RowSeriesLabels { get; set; }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**DataModel.cs**

```
public class DataModel
{
  public DataModel(double value, string label)
  {
    this.Value = value;
    this.Label = label;
  }

  public double Value { get; set; }
  public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think there is a good example of perfect answer as always! I had all public, because I was trying Array approach without any success (quite many attempts given). Otherwise I am trying to keep all private as much as my current skills are capable for. I will test this in upcoming days. After understanding a little bit more a about programming I am struggling to get enough time to all my ideas to be realized =))

Comment: Thank you! I see, you are quite productive. Let me know if I can help.

Comment: There are some errors on some lines. I was able to fix the majority of them. However one of them is `var newDataModel = new DataModel();` - this waiting for variables as it is `public DataModel(double value, string label)`. Maybe you can suggest what it should be? Also this `public CartesianMapper<MeasureModel> RowSeriesConfiguration { get; set; }` should be `public CartesianMapper<DataModel> RowSeriesConfiguration { get; set; }`?

Comment: I have to apologize, seriously. I wrote the code directly in the browser without completion or compiler aid. The constructor issue for instance escaped my attention. The wrong generic parameter type is a remainder of my copy and paste mission. I reused and refactored some existing code of mine and missed to adjust the generic type parameter. I have fixed both errors. Thank you for your patience! ;)

Comment: I was thinking this might be the reason, but this is the next level of coding. There is something still wrong with my setup as bars in chart are not moving, but I will investigate it further myself. By the way if you are interested, I can share this on GitHub as it is my private project. It might be interesting once it will be working (used to track daily activity on computer (data stored locally =)) )), however it is on very early stage and a lot of things to be added. Maybe there is already something similar, my point is to add as much configuration possibilities as possible.

Comment: Ahh, an activity tracker, nice. I think I was close to start one too some time ago. is this considered open-source? I always look to join some interesting projects. _"my point is to add as much configuration possibilities as possible"_ Don't get lost in details. Working too much on details is a real show stopper. From experience I can recommend you to get a running application first before adding features one by one. Otherwise you will very likely kill the project. What is wrong, what do you mean by "bars are not moving"? The above example should really work.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. That's the one. Basically I think there is a core already in place, but some features are not working (they are there but not working correct). I have been trying to add calendar view that I have found around the corner. I was thinking to keep it inside group first and then see in which direction it will go. I can share it in GitHub team (just need to setup one and write some description), however there is a risk you will be amazed by my skills (in a bad way) =D. I think currently problem is with UpdateChart() but need to check it in more detail.

Comment: I guess your nickname on GitHub is the same as here?